# .htaccess redirect any domain/directory to www.domain/directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'd like to use .htaccess to redirect any non-www domain to its www equivalent, regardless of directory - I assume I need multiple RewriteRules

Goal:

```
domain.tld -> www.domain.tld
www.domain.tld -> www.domain.tld
domain.tld/directory -> www.domain.tld/directory
www.domain.tld -> www.domain.tld/directory
```

So far I have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

... but all that does is redirect domain.tld -> www.domain.tld. It does not account for a directory. That is, domain.tld/directory does not redirect to www.domain.tld/directory; it just goes directly to domain.tld/directory

Perhaps I need a separate rewrite rule? I'm cool with that.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: This rule is fine. Do you have another .htaccess somewhere ?

Comment: I do have another htaccess but it does not contain any redirects.
Not a duplicate because that one asks for everything in one statement. I'm asking for one thing: domain.tld/dir -> www.domain.tld/dir